# Wait for two sequences to finish

Tags: system.reactive

I have a code like

```
BusManager.OrderShouldBeCreated.Subscribe(orderShouldBeCreated =>BusManager.PublishAsync(new OrderCreated());
BusManager.PublishAsync(new OrderShouldBeCreated());
```

which asynchronously publish events which then they advance my BusManager sequences (OrderShouldBeCreated,OrderCreated). Right now to wait for the OrderCreated OnNext I used the following after the above call.

```
await Task.WhenAll(
BusManager.OrderShouldBeCreated.ToTask(),
BusManager.OrderCreated.ToTask());
```

I would like to use plain RX though if possible and somehow compose the sequences and remove the Task.WhenAll and ToTask calls.

Comment: It would be awesome to have a [mcve] for this. Can you create a simple example from basic observables that illustrates your requirement?

Comment: I am sorry about this I try better next time, takes a long time to decouple. I can understand that my questions are a bit abstract. I hope I will improve soon as I dive deeper into RX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just translating from what you have, you would end up with

```
await Observable.Merge(
    BusManager.OrderShouldBeCreated.LastAsync(),
    BusManager.OrderCreated.LastAsync()
)
    .Take(2);
```

To help you further, you would have to expand what you're providing.